# array_combine empty values

Tags: php

One array is 35 elements (mysql column names)

Array ( [1] => ID...)

second is only few elements:

```
Array ( [1] => 63 [2] => REF213211 [3] => aaa [7] => Warszawa [8] => Wola [12] => 100 [14] => 1 [15] => 100 [35] => 1 )
```

I need to combine first array as keys for second array

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `foreach` like this:

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
    $combined[$key] = isset($values[$index]) ? $values[$index] : null;
}
```

This will combine the keys in `$keys` with the values in `$values`. If there is no corresponding value in `$values` it will result in `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
$header = ["a", "b", "c"];
$values = array_combine($header, array_fill(0,count($header),null));
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  'a' => NULL
  'b' => NULL
  'c' => NULL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the keys are identical (seems to be in your case), it's simple:

```
$combined_array =  array_combine( array_values($array1), array_values($array2) );
```

if the first array has **more keys** than the second array, you can generate a temporary array for array1 which has only these keys that are in array2 (intersection of keys):

```
$temporary = array_intersect_key( $array1, $array2 );
$combined_array = array_combine( array_values($temporary), array_values($array2) );
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = Array();
foreach( $columnarray as $key => $columnname )
{
if ( isset($secondarray[$key]) ) $newarray[$columnname] = $secondarray[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a hash as the result, iterate over both arrays until the shortest array is completely traversed and put key/value pairs into the hash table.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

```
array_fill_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'], null);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  'a' => NULL
  'b' => NULL
  'c' => NULL
}
```

Comment: Please add the link to the function documentation for reference