# How to combine an array of keys with corresponding values from another array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have 2 arrays

```
Array ( [1] => Manufacturer [2] => Location [3] => Hours [4] => Model )
```

and

```
Array ( [Manufacturer] => John Deere [Location] => NSW [Hours] => 6320 )
```

I need to combine them and associate the values from the first array( Manufacturer, Location, hours , Model) as names in the 2nd array and if a specific values from the first array doesn't find associative name in the 2nd array to associate empty . For the example the result that I need from the above arrays is an array like this

```
   Array ( [Manufacturer] => John Deere [Location] => NSW [Hours] => 6320 [Model] => )
```

If i use simple array_combine it says that PHP Warning:  array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have equal number of elements

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503066

Comment: You wouldn't have had to use array_combine() with the solution I posted in your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514640/php-associative-arrays-regex-array/3514692#3514692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $array1 and $array2 in order as you listed them, I think this would work:

```
$newArray = array();
while (list(,$data) = each($array1)) {
  if (isset($array2[$data])) {
     $newArray[$data] = $array2[$data];
  } else {
     $newArray[$data] = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $combined[$key] = isset($values[$key]) ? $values[$key] : null;
}
```

Where `$keys` is your first array with the keys and `$values` is your second array with the corresponding values. If there is no corresponding value in `$values` the value will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge).  This example appears to do what you want:

```
<?php
$keys = array( 1 => "Manufacturer", 2 => "Location", 3 => "Hours", 4 => "Model") ;
$canonical = array_combine(array_values($keys), array_fill(0, count($keys), null));

$data = array("Manufacturer" => "John Deere", "Location" => "NSW", "Hours" => 6320);

print_r(array_merge($canonical, $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array of keys is $array1, and the associative array with values is $array2:

```
$new_array = array_merge(array_fill_keys(array_flip($array1), ''), $array2));
```

This inverts your key array, filling it with '' values. Then when you merge the arrays, any duplicate keys will be overwritten by the second array, but unfilled keys will remain.